I can't use @react-navigation/drawer example code
I followed this minimal example of drawer-based navigation.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

This is the example code.
I started new project with npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
I never changed any coded. However, I have error.



Seems like error is related to Re-animated.
Have you done babel configurations for reanimated correctly?
try adding following in babel.config.js


module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      {
        relativeSourceLocation: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
};




Thanks, but this is not working.
It doesn't make difference.
